# How to Disable Warning DataTables warning Requested unknown parameter from the data source for row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have two rows within my datatables as follows.

```
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
```

These rows repeat themselves for every record on datatables.  So as you can imagine, I get this error all the time and just need it disabled unless you want to figure out how to make it work.

So how do you disable the warning: DataTables warning  Requested unknown parameter from the data source for row

Answer (score 18):

```
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';

    $('#table').on( 'error.dt', function ( e, settings, techNote, message ) {
    console.log( 'An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message );
    } ) ;
```

Above code will solve problem and also log error in console so you can solve the error

Comment: It helped me disable the error but after inserting errMode=None, my html table is not turning into datatable format, the columns are not sortable anymore.?? @pareshm

Answer (score 3):

Just add `$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw'` to the page where DataTables will be placed.

Edit:

DataTables has evolved more. User `none` in place of `throw` because `throw` may halt execution of the page.

Comment: this stops execution of the rest of the scripts on the page.

Comment: Yeah, I've been able to get along with it for a while. It's only really possible if you modify the source.