# DataTables v1.9.4 DataTables warning (table id = 'tblMyDataTable'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 1

Tags: datatables

Response from server is:

{"aaData":[["01/02/1980","02/02/1980","Text1","321"],["01/02/1990","02/02/1990","Text2","404"],["01/02/2000","02/02/2000","Text3","515"]]}

My HTML is:

```
<table id="tblMyDataTable"> 
    <thead> 
    <tr role="row">
        <th>Date1</th>
    <th>Date2</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Number</th> 
    </tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

and, my javascript is:

```
$('#tblMyDatTable').dataTable();
```

I put above response into dataTable like this:

```
$('#tblMyDatTable').dataTable().fnAddData(data);
```

and get error message in title of this post.

I tried aoColumns as mData and mDataProp per another SO post, same error as above. (And, still puzzled why necessary when DataTables documentation example shows not there, just give  server response to fnAddData.

Comment: fwiw, was following this example for data format: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html  with fnAddData example here: https://datatables.net/api

Comment: Sheeeeeeesh   Change $('#tblMyDatTable').dataTable().fnAddData(data); to $('#tblMyDatTable').dataTable().fnAddData(data.aaData); and it works.

Answer (score 0):

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24786199/849417

add `$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw'` in the page where the plugin is used